# Why Value Formatter gets Applied to the Cell but the Displayed Value does Not Change ag-grid

Tags: angular, cell, ag-grid, formatter

I do have the following *column* and *function* in my ag-grid:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

            this.columnDefs = [
                {
                headerName: 'Header', field: 'quantity',
                valueFormatter: (params) => this.numberFormatter(params),
                }
        ];
   }

  numberFormatter(params){
    console.log(params.value);
    return '$'+params.value;
  }
```

No matter what changes make to the current value **inside** the *numberFormatter*() function, no changes are displayed in the table.

The changes however are visible and **returned** **correctly** within *numberFormatter*() method.

What am I missing?

Comment: I try your code and all work fine for me. Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your data is not presented (or field `quantity` doesn't exist in your data)

You have to define it correctly and it should work as expected

Here exact same <kbd>[**DEMO**](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/vJU3Av2Chuxl2DSS)</kbd> which works

> *you don't need to execute anonymous function in `valueFormatter` definition, you can just assign the function*
>
> ```
> valueFormatter: this.numberFormatter.bind(this)
> ```
>
> *it doesn't affect on result*

Answer (score 0):

Use *valueGetter* instead of *valueFormatter*.